# how to style embedded code, displayed on a webpage

Tags: php, css

I want to display some PHP code on my blog.

I'd love to style this code like the code displayed in codecademy.com.

Is this done using CSS, or Javascript/CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should really provide some code rather than asking a random question.

But as the answer is so simple try this plugin, don't reinvent a very complex wheel!

https://github.com/AndiDittrich/EnlighterJS/

Comment: The answer is far from random.  It doesn't matter what the code is.  It could be any code.  Styling the code is code-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Usually syntax highlighters require both css and javascript. Javascript is needed to parse the code tokens and to wrap them with some markup properly styled.

A good library for syntax highlighting is prism.js : http://prismjs.com/
The download page contains the extension for php language

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know exactly what part of the styling you want, but have a look at Prettyfi: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use any plugins or scripts you can just use the `&lt` and  `&gt` for `<` and `>` and style the code by using CSS as a normal text.

### Example:

#### HTML

```
<code>
&lt?php<br />
<b>$p</b> = "some text";<br />
echo(<b>$p</b>);<br />
?&gt
</code>
```

#### CSS

```
code b{
color: red;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EGe3g/5/